# Unable to add to Table JavaFXML

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, fxml

I have been trying hopelessly for hours to try and figure this one out but I am having no luck. The idea is that when I input the information and press the 'Save Employee' button the table in the center should update accordingly. I know that the method for this is being reached which leads me to believe there is something wrong with the way I have created the table and list.

Edited miminal code:

Controller:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML // fx:id="nameField"
    private TextField nameField;

    @FXML // fx:id="wageField"
    private TextField wageField;

    @FXML // fx:id="saveBtn"
    private Button saveBtn;

    @FXML // fx:id="nameColumn"
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML // fx:id="wageColumn"
    private TableColumn<Employee, Double> wageColumn;

    private TableView<Employee> employeeTable;

    ObservableList<Employee> employeeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataCell -> dataCell.getValue().nameProperty());
        wageColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataCell -> dataCell.getValue().wageProperty().asObject());


    }

    public void saveButtonClick() {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(nameField.getText());
        employee.setWage(Double.parseDouble(wageField.getText()));

        employeeList.add(employee);

    }
}
```

Employee:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Employee {

    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    private DoubleProperty wage = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "wage", 0.0);

    public Double getWage() {
        return wage.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty wageProperty() {
        return wage;
    }

    public void setWage(Double wage) {
        this.wage.set(wage);
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <center>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="wageColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Wage" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
   <left>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label text="Add new Entry" />
            <TextField fx:id="nameField" promptText="name" />
            <TextField fx:id="wageField" promptText="wage" />
            <Button fx:id="saveBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveButtonClick" text="save new entry" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Main:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("debug.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Minimal Debug");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a controller class? If so, why are you creating a `TableView` instance? You don't seem to add this table to the layout anywhere. And please update the code in your question so it is complete, instead of linking to your entire project. Remove everything unnecessary. You only need the table view, columns, and you can presumably reduce the number of properties in your model class to one or two, similarly for the columns. Just hard code an item and add it to the table in the `initialize()` method. That should be enough to reproduce the problem (and if not, you are halfway to solving it).

Comment: @James_D , it is part of the controller class yes. Prior to creating that instance I was getting null pointers. I really wish I knew how to recreate this in a smaller and complete single bit of code but I honestly don't. Im just starting out on JavaFX.

Comment: To create a [MCVE], just try what I said in he previous comment. If you're getting null pointer exceptions it's because the `fx:id ` in your FXML is not matching the field name `employeeTable`, or something else is wrong with the FXML injection. Creating a completely new table which is never displayed is not going to fix the problem...

Comment: @James_D , right I have got it into minimal format. One weird thing I found is that when I try and add the line "  employeeTable.setItems(employeeList);" to my actual project thats where I get the null pointer exception. However when I add it to this little debug thing it works fine?!?! The functionality still does not work however with adding to the table. Hope this is what you meant. I tried

Comment: Thanks for the update. You're just not injecting the `TableView` into the controller (as you are doing correctly with the `TableColumn`s and `TextField`s). Is there a reason you omitted that for the table?

Comment: Hmm, not 100% sure I follow. Do you mean as I haven't done @FXML? Also any idea why when I had that line I mentioned in the previous comment it works in one but not the other? Thanks

Comment: I get the null pointer exception in this example if I add that line to `initialize()`. See answer for why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the `TableView` into the controller, in the same way you are doing with the other controls. I.e.

```
// add @FXML annotation
@FXML
private TableView<Employee> employeeTable;
```

and

```
<!-- note fx:id attribute -->
<TableView fx:id="employeeTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
```

and then you can set the data to the table in the `initialize()` method:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataCell -> dataCell.getValue().nameProperty());
    wageColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataCell -> dataCell.getValue().wageProperty().asObject());

    employeeTable.setItems(employeeList);
}
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! As if to think such a simple oversight has cost me so much time, all part of learning this I guess. The functionality now works spot on as intended. Again, thanks a lot for your quick and polite replies.

Comment: If something in your controller is null, it's usually because your `fx:id` is wrong or you are missing the `@FXML` (or both).

Comment: Written down on a card, will remember this Im sure!

Comment: just a final thought. Do you know of any useful resources when it comes to JavaFX / FXML?

Comment: A lot of people like this [tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/). I just learned mostly from the [official Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) and the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm), and then browsing this forum.